# Create a thumbnail from uploaded pdf

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am trying to make a preview from pdf that users must to upload. I am using 1and1 hosting server, so I don´t have total control about what to install, and I don´t know how to install ImageMagick. I followed [these steps](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/webspace-and-access-c85098/ssh-c37775/install-imagemagick-via-ssh-a649013.html) and I was using this code (that is working in a different project using a VPS):

```
private function preViewPDF($filename)
{
    $img_path = './assets/uploads/previews';
    $file_name = explode(".", $filename)[0].".jpg";
    $dir = './assets/upload/files/';

    $img = new Imagick($dir."/".$filename.'[0]');
    $img->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $img->writeImage($img_path."/".$file_name);
    return "previews/".$id.$type."/".$file_name;
}
```

After try that and get Imagick Class not Found Exception, I am trying to convert using exec command:

## Actual code

```
private function preViewPDF($filename)
{
    $file_name = explode(".", $filename)[0].".jpg";
    $dir = getcwd().'/assets/uploads/files/';
    if(file_exists($dir."/".$filename))
    {
        exec("convert ".$dir."/".$filename.'[0]'." ".$dir."/".$file_name, $output, $return_var);
        var_dump($output);
        echo "<br>";
        var_dump($return_var);
    }
    else echo "no file";
    echo "<br>".$dir."/".$filename.'[0]'."<br>";
    echo "<br>".$file_name."<br>";
}
```

The var_dump($output); throws an empty array. And the $return_var is 1... general error :(
If I change the value between [] (the number of the page I want to convert) $output throws:

```
array(3) {   
    [0]=> string(0) ""   
    [1]=> string(70) "Requested FirstPage is greater than the number of pages in the file: 1" 
    [2]=> string(53) " No pages will be processed (FirstPage > LastPage)."   
}
```

So... any ideas what am I doing wrong?? Thank you.

## Extra Data

Only two little things more (maybe obvious). The first, if I emulate the order on a SSL connection it works (I get a image from a pdf). And second, permissions are not the reason (I tried to create and write a file -with fopen and fwrite- and it works).

## EDIT

First, an explanation about my actual code:

```
$file_name = explode(".", $filename)[0].".jpg";
```

This line is because the extension of $filename is .pdf, so I need remove this part and concatenate the right extension .jpg (from hello.pdf I get hello.jpg).

```
$dir = getcwd().'/assets/uploads/files/';
```

This is the folder where the pdf is uploaded and the jpg preview must be saved.

```
if(file_exists($dir."/".$filename))
```

I put this line, simply because I though that the uploading of the pdf wasn´t finished and this was the reason that doesn´t work.

```
exec("convert ".$dir."/".$filename.'[0]'." ".$dir."/".$file_name, $output, $return_var);
```

This is the line where the command convert is executed... but doesn´t work.

Second thing is a new simple code I just tried:

```
if(file_exists("./DpRPJTmfSArPRuGZrOddLendfbhgHTrydwukMRvOMuSzVMDuBb.pdf"))
{
    exec("convert ./DpRPJTmfSArPRuGZrOddLendfbhgHTrydwukMRvOMuSzVMDuBb.pdf[0] ./DpRPJTmfSArPRuGZrOddLendfbhgHTrydwukMRvOMuSzVMDuBb.jpg", $output, $return_var);
    var_dump($output);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($return_var);
}
else echo "no hay fichero";
```

The $output is empty, and the $return_var is 1.

Comment: Where is your Imagemagick `convert` command installed? Try running `which convert` in the shell/Terminal and then putting the full path to it in your `exec(..)`

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell. How I said, I follow this steps https://ayuda.1and1.es/hosting-c85122/scripting-y-programacion-c64780/php-c64788/uso-de-imagemagick-a792786.html to install ImageMagick on the 1and1 web hosting, and it is assumed that the installation folder must be: /kunden/homepages/4/1and1ID_client/htdocs/ImageMagick/ but the output of `which convert` is /usr/bin/convert And I tried it too... but didn´t work.

Comment: Sorry, these steps NO, these others: https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/webspace-and-access-c85098/ssh-c37775/install-imagemagick-via-ssh-a649013.html

Answer (score 1):

Forget all the dross and start simple with the file in the same folder as the code to see if Imagemagick is working.

```
 convert input.pdf output.jpg
```

Also you have so many variables etc. in the Imagemagick code it is hard to read it.
I am also confused by your code and I would create the filename and path outside the convert code and you can echo it to ensure it contains what you expect.

This looks wrong:

```
 $filename.'[0]'
```

I would try:

```
 $filename[0]
```

I assume your pdf has more than one page?

**Edit**

Try this code - it has a different way of displaying any errors and allows you to view the contents of your command if you have lots of variables etc.

```
$error=array(); 
echo "<pre>"; 
$cmd = "./DpRPJTmfSArPRuGZrOddLendfbhgHTrydwukMRvOMuSzVMDuBb.pdf[0] ./DpRPJTmfSArPRuGZrOddLendfbhgHTrydwukMRvOMuSzVMDuBb.jpg";
// You can use this line to see what the $cmd ontains when using a lot of variables
echo $cmd;
exec("$cmd 2>&1", $error);  
echo "<br>".print_r($error)."<br>";  
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi @Bonzo, I just edited the question to explain a little the code. How you see I make it the most simple possible. Still doesn´t work. And about make this:  $filename[0], I didn´t try, but I think it will not work,  $filename is not array, and it will throw out of index exception (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

I make preview with this:

```
exec('convert -density 300 -trim "'.$file.'" -resize 600 -quality 85 -colorspace RGB -background white  "'.$destination.'" &', $output, $return_var);
```

Where $file is tue original and $destination is the name of image.
With the & at the end, each image will be named image-0.jpg, image-1.jpg..

$return_var == 0 when all is OK